# regex to accept number in fomat 00.00

Tags: javascript, html, regex, typescript

In my Angular App  I am trying to set validation on input field such as

it should accept only 2 digit number or floating point number with 2 digit after point and before point too

Example

Accepted value

3,
33,
33.3,
33.33

Max value can be 99.99

Not accepting

333
33.333
3.333
333.33

Currently I am using

```
pattern="[+]?((\d{1,2})+(?:[\.][0-9]{0,2})?|\.[0-9]{0,2})$"
```

it validate 2 digit after point but failed to validate two digit before point as it accept 333.33 (which is wrong)

I also tried

```
pattern="[+]?(([0-9])+(?:[\.][0-9]{0,2})?|\.[0-9]{0,2})$"
```

But same thing happen , it does not validate two digit before point

Comment: `it does not validate two digit before point` because you don't put any restriction on that. And the whole regex is way too convoluted than needed.

Comment: I tried this ^[0-9]{1,2}+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$ , it works when I test on https://regex101.com/r/VBC2vS/1 , but not work in input element

Comment: and I did put validation , see first regex (\d{1,2})

Comment: `[0-9]{1,2}+` well, you allow either one or two digits but ANY AMOUNT of either one or two digits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This pattern `(\d{1,2})+` will match 1 - 2 digits and will repeat that one or more times.

A pattern like `\.[0-9]{0,2}` will also match just a single dot because the digits will match 0 - 2 times.

You could use an anchor to assert the start `^` and the end `$` of the string. Match 1 or 2 digits with an optional part that matches a dot and 1 or 2 digits:

`^\d{1,2}(?:\.\d{1,2})?$`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gaO3Rp/1)

**Explanation**

- `^` Assert the start of the string
- `\d{1,2}` Match a digit 1 or 2 times
- `(?:` [Non capturing](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html) group

  - `\.\d{1,2}` Match a dot literally and 1 or 2 digits
- `)?` Close non capturing group and make it optional
- `$` Assert the end of the string

If you want to match an optional plus at the beginning, the start of the regex could be`^\+?`

```js
let pattern = /^\d{1,2}(?:\.\d{1,2})?$/;
let strs = [
  "99",
  "3",
  "33",
  "33.3",
  "33.33",
  "333",
  "33.333",
  "3.333",
  "333.33"
];

strs.forEach((s) => {
  console.log(s + " ==> " + pattern.test(s));
});
```

Comment: Great , can you explain how it match ?

Comment: @Jack I have added an explanation.

Comment: One more question - (?:\.\d{1,2})?  here which ? set it as optional . First ? or last ?

Comment: `(?:` starts a non capturing group. `)?` This closes the non capturing group and the question mark makes it optional. I have updated the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me the  regular expression can be simplified. Do you really want an optional leading "+"? I've left it out as your examples don't include it, put it back in if you want.

```js
function testValue(){
  // Optional leading +
  // var re = /^\+?\d{1,2}(\.\d{1,2})?$/;
  // No leading +
  var re = /^\d{1,2}(\.\d{1,2})?$/;
  console.log(re.test(this.value));
}


window.onload = function(){
  document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('input',testValue,false);
}
```

```html
Enter number: <input>
```